# Data created with class failes to be displayed with flask app into html

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, post

I'm tring to make a flask application for a tool that I've created in my internship. I have a class Activities that can generate a pandas dataframe, and I wish to display it into a table in an HTML using flask. I tested a simple example that works just fine and displays the given dataframe, but as soon as I try doing the same thing with Activites class, it doesn't work. The code in itself doesn't result in any errors in the kernel but when I go to http://localhost:5000/, my web browser(Chrome) says localhost does not allow the connection : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The class takes up to 15 minutes just to create the data, I was thinking that maybe the Chrome does not like to wait such a long time and just refuses the connection ?
I am new with Flask so I am very confused. Thank you for your help :)

This is the simple working code :

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/task1')
def task1():
    return render_template('task1.html')

@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    return render_template('simple.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is what I'm trying to do that doesn't work :

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from activities import Activities

app = Flask(__name__) 

activities = Activities()

activities.load_data()

df = activities.raw_data.head()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/task1')
def search_for_sailors():
    return render_template('task1.html')

@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    return render_template('simple.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach that I use for data that takes time to get back to client is AJAX to get data post page load.

1. changed `/handle_data` route to respond to **GET** plus move *heavy* lifting build of data frame into it (logically)
2. use `Response()` flask object to return html of data frame
3. use JQuery to do AJAX call to this `/handle_data` route to get HTML of table

**app.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/task1')
def task1():
    return render_template('task1.html')

@app.route('/handle_data')
def handle_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
    return Response(df.to_html())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="main">
        <section id="data-section">
            <h2>Data</h2>
            <div id="data"/>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
<script>
    function apicall(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:url,
            success: (data) => {
                $("#data").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

  window.onload = function () {
    apicall("/handle_data");
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JQuery or AJAX, do you have another solution ? Or perhas a link to learn the basics ? Thank you for help.

Comment: home.html example I provided is everything you need to get working with both.  Try it out with app.py that I provided and it's a full example of what I described

Comment: Should I call my class inside handle_data() ? Because when I create it outside the app, it keeps running over and over again in the background.

Comment: that's the idea - it's the long running process.   if it's very long running you should consider calculating outside the flask app periodically, saving down and then reloading in handle_data().

Comment: What does it mean to run it periodically ?

Comment: I was an intern 30 years ago....  a common pattern for data/calculations that are expensive to prepare is to prepare it once a day then use / present it multiple times per day.  Hence you can create your data frame in another python class and save it using say https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html to a file then use `read_pickle()` when you want to display it in your web page

Comment: Okay I see, I'll try it. Thank you very much !